# What is the alternative to closing posts marked, subjective/non-programming related/community-wiki

Tags: discussion, subjective

While I understand the need for getting a precise/objective answer to questions, I do feel that SO is becoming pedantic and totalitarian. If a question is tagged as **subjective/non-programming related/community-wiki/fun/off-topic**, does it really require voted to death [closed]? The OP has clearly made his intention, why not live with it. No one can game a CW post.

I remember SO being fun and witty. Almost every question spawned curiosity. What else does a programmer crave for! Paraphrasing voltaire, "One may not agree with what the other says, but one should definitely stand up for the right of others to say so". I have found some great insights in smart retorts and regret missing that. Why not have a different section for that because of the **close** trigger happy guys

Comment: exactly the reason, why I am voted as troll! no explanation given.

Comment: Down voting on meta is more a sign of people disagreeing with you than that anything is wrong with your post.

Answer (score 4):

> While I understand the need for getting a precise/objective answer to questions, I do feel that SO is becoming pedantic and totalitarian. If a question is tagged as subjective/non-programming related/community-wiki/fun/off-topic, does it really require voted to death [closed]? The OP has clearly made his intention, why not live with it. No one can game a CW post.

Just because it is tagged correctly and CW doesn't mean it should be allowed. The majority of the questions wouldn't have been asked if the user had read the FAQ

> **What kind of questions should I not ask here?**
>
> Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion. This is not a discussion board, this is a place for questions that can be answered!

I for one am fed up of questions like "What is the one programming skill you have always wanted to master but haven’t had time?" coming up on the front page. It is not the intention of the site to be a discussion board full of questions that cannot be conclusively answered.

Answer (score 2):

The alternatives are

1. *not asking off topic questions*
2. taking them to some forum or chatroom where they *are on topic*.